# SEHE Exception running R script with RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm getting the exception `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in RDotNet.dll`

by running a simple R script:

```
n + minWidth
```

with this code in c#:

```
// Load the R environment
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

// Load the input data
CharacterVector charVec = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new List<string> { csvFileName });
engine.SetSymbol("input", charVec);
engine.SetSymbol("n", engine.CreateNumeric(numberOfFanfolds));
engine.SetSymbol("minWidth", engine.CreateNumeric(minWidth));
engine.SetSymbol("minScrap", engine.CreateNumeric(minScrap));
engine.SetSymbol("cardboardStep", engine.CreateNumeric(cardboardStep));

// Run the script
results = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => engine.Evaluate("source('" + script_file_ + "')"));
```

When i try to run the code directly it works correctly:

```
var results = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => engine.Evaluate("n + minWidth"));
```

What does it means? What can I do? Do I need to format the R script in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to rearrange the file path

```
script_file_ = scriptFile.Replace("\\", "/");
```